# About batched effect of matmul in PyTorch——When to reduce?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

How does bp work in batched matmul scene? assume we have a linear, the shape of x is `[b,m,k]`, shape of W is `[k,n]`:

```
    y = xW
```

then:

```
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial W} = x^T\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}
```

so what had happened in backward of W?

1. We save the full $x^T$ tensor `[b,k,m]`, and execute the batched matmul  `[b,k,m] x [b,m,n]`, finally reduce the result to `[k,n]` to get the gradient.
2. We directly save the averaged $x^T$ tensor `[k,m]`, and execute the batched matmul  `[k,m] x [m,n]` to get the gradient.

I have read PyTorch's source code, but I have problems to understand it.